# 'CustomAction' to cancel install using WiX

Tags: vbscript, installation, wix

I want a CustomAction in [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) that make the installation cancel after running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the correct error code from your custom action. There is a MSDN article on this, *[Return Values of JScript and VBScript Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371254%28VS.85%29.aspx)*.

Comment: Thanks so much! Its so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to invent a wheel here - WiX has a [standard custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixexitearlywithsuccess.htm) for this.